# How to use the "Sense Function" of RT9080?

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator

I'm testing the [RT9080](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2183318.pdf) as a voltage regulator, and on the datasheet I do not have too much information on what the "Sense Function" is.
I have the circuit connection, but how does it work, and how to use it?

In my case I was expecting info that can help to get the state of charge of the battery in order to integrate a battery level check in my build with an Arduino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regulator senses its output voltage and then uses that signal to regulate voltage. The sense pin is used to sense the output voltage:

[image]

(Taken from the datasheet)

If you buy the version with the external sense pin you must hook this up to the output. Presumably you would do this close to the load to avoid any voltage drop in traces.

Comment: Thank you, its usefulness is clearer now.

Comment: But, why we would check the output voltage if we already have it on output pin where we can sense it? Would be more sens to sense the input voltage right?

Comment: @Unicorn This is a high current regulator, so it may have voltage drop in traces. Measuring the voltage at the load will reduce this effect.